# Get the frames values from the frames bytes

Tags: python, audio, aif

i'm using the aifc library for open an aif file and his method readframes(nframes) for read the frame in bytes.
But now i have to convert the bytes in a float list of values.

How can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

Did you look at the [struct](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html) lib in python standard lib?